# No color in Bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <a class="navbar-brand nav-space" href="#top">
        <img src="img/favicon.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="random image">
        title
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#top">random <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">random</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">random</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">random</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

for my project. However, the color of the navbar is all white, while the examples on https://getbootstrap.com has a greyish navbar. I have already included all bootstrap files.What am I doing wrong? and also, would it be possible to acquire the previous bootstrap 3 navbar styling?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWCGD.jpg

Comment: May be some custom styles overriding the bootstrap styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bg-light as a class in the nav tag.

Comment: Wow thank you :D that solved the problem.I guess I should have done more research. Sorry for posting some nonsense :(